# Microsoft Graph - Office 365 API , Obtain Information about mailbox

Tags: azure, rest, microsoft-graph-api, postman, office365

I'm using O365 Collector template through Postman Agent.
I looked into the documentation and I'm looking for the REST route to discover these informations:

- Number of Mail accounts and their type (if they are shared mailbox, user mailbox)
- On which system (Exchange 2016 ? Online?)

Could someone please link me the documentation to obtain these informations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find what you need is to read the documentation for Outlook mail API.

To differentiate between user mailbox and shared mailbox you need to call Graph API beta and read mailbox settings and read `userPurpose` property.

I did not find any information how to find the version of Exchange. Probably, it's not available.

Resources:

[Outlook mail API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview)

[Mailbox settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) (beta API)

[User purpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/userpurpose?view=graph-rest-beta)